# Is it possible for the Suicide Mission to be impossible?

Tags: mass-effect-2

Is it possible to play Mass Effect 2 so badly (loyalty, recruitment, etc) that the suicide mission is impossible to complete without Shepard dying at the end?

Update:

The definition of impossible in this case is entering the Omega Relay (and therefore passing the point of no return) with a sufficiently bad game state that no combination of decisions can lead to Shepard surviving and the save being importable.

Comment: What do you consider "impossible"? In particular, are you looking for a situation where, if you start the Suicide Mission at that very moment, Shepard will inevitably die (but you could also complete more regular missions), or a situation where you've completed all the other missions and your only option is to start the Suicide Mission and die?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

The only criteria for Shepherd surviving is (not sure if you wanted spoilers or not)

> How many squadmates are alive. If you have 0 or 1 squadmates after beating the final boss, Shepherd will fail to catch the shuttle out (literally no one there to catch them), and die as the base explodes.

My guess this is a practical limitation --

> -- 0 or 1 surviving squadmates means Shepherd can't form a full party of 3, and the game may not be adequately able to handle that -- better, then, to give a game over, rather than dedicating time and programmer hours to bulletproof the game for a tiny fraction of a fraction of games played.

This is actually a bit tricky to pull off in regular gameplay, because

> Loyal squadmates taken into the final fight do not die, so if you *do* take two loyal squadmates into the fight, it is impossible for shepherd to fail -- there's your 2 survivors right there.

The precise parameters of how to achieve this are numerous and varied, so if this is something you desire to plan out, I leave it as an exercise to the reader to plan precisely how to achieve this. I recommend a Suicide Mission flowchart, such as **SPOILER WARNING**: [this one](https://i.redd.it/illia8pzcdd41.jpg).

Comment: Not sure if you wanna look though some runs of people trying to be the worst Shepard: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKoR6OZR51M

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMejR-KUeNA

Answer (score 4):

If you enter the Omega 4 relay with Tali, Mordin, Garrus, Miranda, Jacob, Thane, Jack and Kasumi (so no Grunt, Samara, Zaeed or Legion) with no ship shield/armour/weapon upgrades and Jacob and Miranda being unloyal there is no way to save Shepard.

Jack and Thane die on the ship. Someone else will die here. No way to save the vent person. The seeker swarm will kill someone and it will be Garrus if he is alive. An unloyal Miranda will survive being the second fire team leader.

At the final battle at best you can have Miranda, Jacob and one of Tali or Kasumi. And with two unloyal party members with a defence score 1 and a loyal party member you can't have two Squadmates live and thus Shepard dies.

Comment: Huh, so this is basically losing due to not having enough bodies to take hits. And the cure is to go on more recruitment. I guess having even 1 more person, no matter their loyalty, would make the suicide mission a "success"?

Comment: With one more recruited you can save Garrus and have him and Jacob and/or Miranda hold the line and have them both survive which will mean Shepard survives.